# Unable to delete Azure Virtual Network Gateway using Resource Manager

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-vpn

I created an Azure Virtual Network using PowerShell:

```
$gwpip= New-AzureRmPublicIpAddress -Name TestVNet -ResourceGroupName TestRg -Location 'West Europe' -AllocationMethod Dynamic -DomainNameLabel TestVNet
$vnet = Get-AzureRmVirtualNetwork -Name TestVNet -ResourceGroupName TestRg
$subnet = Get-AzureRmVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name 'GatewaySubnet' -VirtualNetwork $vnet
$gwipconfig = New-AzureRmVirtualNetworkGatewayIpConfig -Name TestVNet -SubnetId $subnet.Id -PublicIpAddressId $gwpip.Id 
New-AzureRmVirtualNetworkGateway -Name TestVNet -ResourceGroupName TestRg -Location 'West Europe' -IpConfigurations $gwipconfig -GatewayType Vpn -VpnType RouteBased
```

This worked perfectly. I now want to delete this Virtual Network Gateway, but that doesn't seem to work. When I use the delete button in the Portal I get a message: "Successfully saved configuration changes to virtual network TestVNet"

When I use PowerShell it doesn't return anything, unless I use the -debug and -verbose switch.

```
Remove-AzureRmVirtualNetworkGateway -Name TestVNet -ResourceGroupName TestRg -Force -Verbose -Debug
```

The final HTTP response says:

```
Body:
{
  "status": "Failed",
  "error": {
  "code": "InternalServerError",
  "message": "An error occured.",
  "details": []
}
```

When I check the audit logs in the Portal I see two Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworkGateways/delete events, both Informational. The first has status Started, the second Accepted. After that, nothing happens anymore. Using the Portal or PowerShell doesn't make a difference in the audit log.

Any suggestions on how I can remove the gateway?

Answer (score 0):

Whilst this isn't the nicest way, I've found you can do the following

Remove Azure PowerShell 1.0 or use a machine with Azure PowerShell 0.9 installed

Connect up to your Tenant

*Import-Module Azure*

*Add-AzureAccount*

*Switch-AzureMode -Name AzureResourceManager*

Then from here force remove the Resource Group housing everything - Be warned, this will delete everything in the resource group

*Remove-AzureResourceGroup -Name TestRg -Force -Verbose*

After a while, everything will be gone. Whilst it doesn't remove just the VNet, or the Gateway, or just the Connection, it will give you a blank test bed again.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It is a workaround still, and it takes > 1 hour for PowerShell to finish (if it ever does, but in the portal the gateway is gone) it does the trick. Let's hope Microsoft comes up with a more decent way to remove the gateway.

Comment: Remove-AzureRmResourceGroup : ResourceGroupDeletionFailed: The deletion of resource group 'TestRg' did not finish within allowed time. Resource group provision
ing state rolled back. Please check audit logs for more details.
At line:1 char:5
+     Remove-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name 'TestRg' -Force -Confir ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Remove-AzureRmResourceGroup], CloudException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Hyak.Common.CloudException,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Resources.RemoveAzureResourceGroupCommand